# Aligning nodes to center in \tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create the following diagram:

```
          |Welcome|
|Low|                   |High|

         |Truth|

          |Lie|
```

So far, this is what I've come up with:

[image]

The idea is that the node `Welcome` is in the center of the page, with `Low` and `High` on either sides of it. Then, the nodes `Truth` and `Lie` should be in the center of the page again.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{comp1} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=4cm, fill=gray!50]
\tikzstyle{comp2} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=4cm]
\tikzstyle{comp3} = [draw, ellipse, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=4cm, fill=gray!10, text centered]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
%%% NODES %%%
\node (welcome)     [comp1]                             {Welcome};

\node (low)         [comp2, below of=welcome]           {Low};
\node (high)        [comp2, right of=low, xshift=3cm]   {High};
\node (truth)       [comp3, below of=low]               {Truth};
\node (lie)         [comp3, below of=truth]             {Lie};

%%% ARROWS %%%
\draw [arrow] (welcome) -- (low);
\draw [arrow] (welcome) -- (high);
\draw [arrow] (low) -- (truth);
\draw [arrow] (high) -- (truth);
\draw [arrow] (truth) -- (lie);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm aware that this might have a simple solution, but I can't seem to find it, even after googling around. So, can anyone help?

Comment: Add a helper-node `\node[below of=welcome, shape=coordinate](tmp){}; \node[comp2, left of=tmp](low){Low};\node[comp2, right of=tmp](high){High};\node[comp3, below left of=tmp](truth){Truth};` I'll add an Answer when I'm at a computer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add an `coordinate` `below of=welcome` and then use it as reference:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{comp1} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=4cm, fill=gray!50]
\tikzstyle{comp2} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=4cm]
\tikzstyle{comp3} = [draw, ellipse, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=4cm, fill=gray!10, text centered]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.2cm]
%%% NODES %%%
\node (welcome)     [comp1]                 {Welcome};
\coordinate[below of=welcome] (c);
\node (low)         [comp2, left of=c]      {Low};
\node (high)        [comp2, right of=c]     {High};
\node (truth)       [comp3, below of=c]     {Truth};
\node (lie)         [comp3, below of=truth] {Lie};

%%% ARROWS %%%
\draw [arrow] (welcome) -- (low);
\draw [arrow] (welcome) -- (high);
\draw [arrow] (low) -- (truth);
\draw [arrow] (high) -- (truth);
\draw [arrow] (truth) -- (lie);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

Some "standard" improvements as suggested by *Gonzalo Medina*:

- `below=of welcome` instead of `below of=welcome`
- or (if you like) more precise `below=2.4cm of welcome`
- `\tikzset` (new syntax) instead of `\tikzstyle` (old syntax)

Related:
[Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/18520)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    comp1/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=4cm, fill=gray!50},
    comp2/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=4cm},
    comp3/.style={draw, ellipse, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=4cm, fill=gray!10, text centered},
    arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm and 1cm]
%%% NODES %%%
\node [comp1]                 (welcome) {Welcome};
\coordinate[below=of welcome] (c);
\node [comp2, left=of c]      (low)     {Low};
\node [comp2, right=of c]     (high)    {High};
\node [comp3, below=of c]     (truth)   {Truth};
\node [comp3, below=of truth] (lie)     {Lie};

%%% ARROWS %%%
\draw [arrow] (welcome) -- (low);
\draw [arrow] (welcome) -- (high);
\draw [arrow] (low)     -- (truth);
\draw [arrow] (high)    -- (truth);
\draw [arrow] (truth)   -- (lie);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also suggest "standard" improvements:  1) Instead of the old `of=` syntax, one should use the `positioning` library and the more versatile and precise `=of` syntax. 2) Instead of `\tikzstyle`, use `\tikzset`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for your comment, I have added an improved version.